# SQL Server identity counterpart problem

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, identity

I'm using SQL Server and I want to use identity constraint in it

I know how to use it in following manner

```
create table mytable
(
 c1 int primary key identity(1,1);
)
```

the above code works fine but what if i want the identity column to have values as EMP001, EMP002,... instead of 1,2....

Thanks in advance,
Guru

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identity columns can only be integers. If you want it to "look like" EMP001, EMP002, etc then that's simply a display issue and not a storage one (that is, you don't need to *store* "EMP001", "EMP002" etc, just store it as 1, 2, 3 via a normal identity column and *display* it in your application as "EMP001", "EMP002", etc)

Comment: Thanks for you support dear.

I appreciate the way you thought.

Answer (score 2):

Create a computed column that concatenates like this:

`'EMP' + RIGHT('00' + CAST(c1 AS varchar(3)), 3)`

Otherwise an IDENTITY column as surrogate key is just that: a meaningless number.

I assume you're only going to have 999 rows or is there another sequence somewhere?