# Identity key on varchar column - T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, calculated-columns

I want to know if I can create an Identity (auto increment on a Varchar column. and how can I make it a primary key and create foreign key references on other table.

This is the code i have -

```
CREATE TABLE Questions(
    QuestionID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, 
    QuestionNo as 'Q'+Cast(QuestionID as Varchar(10),       
    Question Varchar(200)
)
```

Is there a way I can make QuestionNo as Primary key and reference it in another table (say Answers (AnswerID, QuestionNo, AnswerText)?

Comment: **this is a bad design, don't do it!** you can always display (in the application) the numeric value with a "Q" prefix but store it as a pure int, and FK to the int.  If you need to, you can FK to two clumns, the int and a char(1) type. there is no need to store it as a varchar.  I fight with old code that has this same crazy concept in it, makes everything a hack, you'll eventully have code like `IF LEFT(...,1)='Q'... ELSE IF LEFT(...,1)='A'...` or similar `CASE` statements...

Comment: Yes.I get your point. Thanks.

Comment: @KM: Agreed.  I had one system that had a setup similar to this - they wanted the numbers to have a couple of letters leading into the record number... It got better when they started using the system, and wanted the search updated so it *ignored the leading letters*...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked for me on SQL Server 2005:

```
CREATE TABLE Questions(
  QuestionID int IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
  QuestionNo as 'Q'+Cast(QuestionID as Varchar(10)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY, 
  Question Varchar(200)
)
```

The main part is that a computed column needs the PERSISTED keyword...

Comment: But how would you refer this in another table as a foreign key?
I get Error from this

CREATE TABLE Answers(AnswerID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, QuestionNo Varchar(10), Answer nvarchar(200),      Foreign key (QuestionNo) references Questions(QuestionNo))

Comment: @Abey: You get an error because the length of the `questionno` is VARCHAR(10) in the `ANSWERS` table, but it's VARCHAR(11) in `QUESTIONS` - once that's corrected, it works for me.  But I agree with `gbn` - I wouldn't make `questionno` the primary key both for speed & likelihood of format change in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Not directly.

- use a computed column on an integer column (as per OMG Ponies answer)
- use a udf ([SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486483), [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987071))

My question is: why? it will be slower than a straightforward number.

Comment: Just wanted the identity key to be more descriptive like Q1, Q2 
rather than plan numbers

Answer (score -1):

this code is working

```
CREATE TABLE IdentityExample(
  ID int IDENTITY NOT NULL, 
  QNo as 'Q'+Cast(ID as Varchar(10)) PERSISTED PRIMARY KEY, 
  name Varchar(200)
)
```